# how to prevent meteor from reconnecting to the server

Tags: meteor

i want to only use the client side part of meteor, but it constantly try to reconnect to the server (which in my case will be a astatic ngnix).

Is there a way to prevent these reconnects, so that the socketjs not always trys that in the background?

Comment: If you're "only using the client side part of meteor", why not just use a Javascript MVC framework? Isn't the whole point of meteor to hook up a bunch of clients in real time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a hack, but you can set `Meteor.default_connection._stream._retryTimeout` to a large value (to prevent reconnects) and then call `Meteor.default_connection._stream._lostConnection()` (to abort the initial connection attempt).